# CSS container doesn't stretch to accommodate floats

Tags: html, css, css-float

```
<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">

  .container {
      width: 900px;
      border: 2px solid #333333;
      padding-top: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 30px;
  }

  .container_left {
      border: 2px solid #FF00FF;
      width: 650px;
      float: left;
  }

  .container_right {
      border: 2px solid #0000FF;
      width: 225px;
      float: right;
  }

</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="container_left">
        <div>LEFT CONTAINER</div>
        <div>LEFT CONTAINER</div>
        <div>LEFT CONTAINER</div>
        </div>

        <div class="container_right">
        <div>RIGHT CONTAINER</div>
        <div>RIGHT CONTAINER</div>
        <div>RIGHT CONTAINER</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The result is:
[image: result]

I want a result like this:
[image: desired result]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the `.container` selector. This will force the container to acknowledge that it has children.

Comment: If it were as easy with deadbeat dads! :)

Answer (score 25):

Give the container a

```
overflow: auto
```

or

```
overflow: hidden
```

see [**this page on quirksmode.org**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) for details on the issue.

Answer (score 12):

A *quick fix* is to add `overflow: hidden` to your `.container`.

**This is not the best solution** per say, merely the *quickest fix*.  Your best solution would be to implement and apply [clearfix](http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/06/new-clearfix-hack/) as it doesn't have issues with printing due to overflow.

In the event you use `overflow: auto` or `overflow: hidden` and a user attempts to print the page, content that does not fit on the printed page will be clipped because:

1. scroll-bars do not print
2. hidden content does not display

Comment: +1 because this is the only answer that mentions downsides to the `overflow` method. It's also worth mentioning that this method may result in unwanted clipping/scrollbars where the content would otherwise overflow.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to put in a `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` just before closing the container div.

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="container_left">
    <div>LEFT CONTAINER</div>
    <div>LEFT CONTAINER</div>
    <div>LEFT CONTAINER</div>
    </div>

    <div class="container_right">
    <div>RIGHT CONTAINER</div>
    <div>RIGHT CONTAINER</div>
    <div>RIGHT CONTAINER</div>
    </div>

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

to the outer div you might want to use the clearfix css, explained here: http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

Answer (score 1):

```
.clear:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
* html .clear { height: 1%; }
*:first-child+html .clear { min-height: 1px; }
```

Apply .clear to your parent element.

Answer (score 1):

This might be of help ["Clearing a float container"](http://positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html)